# Powershell Function set value via the function

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, powershell

I am having a whale of a time trying to figure this out.

here is my code.

```
function set-region {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter( ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$defaultregion = 'us-east-1'
    )

    BEGIN {
        
    }

    PROCESS {

        Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region $defaultregion

    }

    END{

    }  

}
```

I am not able to set the default aws region using this function.

the ultimate goal is to set the aws region by calling set-region using us-east-1 as default or any value that is given for region like eu-east-2 etc.

when I try to dot source this code, it does not work.

any help is much appreciated as I am completely lost.

sorry for a novice question.

Comment: "when I try to dot source this code, it does not work." - please explain what that means. What exactly did you expect to happen, and what did (or didn't) happen, and how did you test it? :)

Comment: hey thanks for reaching out. Okay so when I dot source the code, I call the function. nothing works, it does not return default region. I test that by Get-DefaultRegion, The value is null. function that I dot source did not pass or set value for default aws region.

Comment: Have you tried calling `set-region` after the function is loaded in memory; or remove the first and last line of your script above, then dot-sourcing it?

Comment: Hey, good day, I have tried that too, and it does not load. there is no errors, either with or without cmdletbinding, I can run the script and everything loads to memory. But the region does not set.